# Fields parameters with hyphen in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails adopt camelcase or underscore naming convention and this is given.

But what if the data that is to be stored in a Rails app has different naming conventions?

For example an 3rd party API may return some parameters as 'fieldId' but also as 'field-id'.

In the case of a parameter like 'field-id' how can a MVC be designed in Rails to accommodate this scenario? If a resource is named 'field_id' Rails simply ignore the parameter 'field-id' and the data is not saved - good thing from security perspective, but still the business problem is present.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite normal that a third party system does not conform with your own internal structure. You can try to change your own structure, but normally should just build something that translates between the external and the internal structure.
This is so common that there is are several pattern for this, for example the : [adapter-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

If you want some more specific advice, you need to be more specific yourself, what is this API, how do you access it.  If you are talking about HTTP-Post-Parameters, you just write a method that take a hash as input and outputs another hash, with different key names.

Comment: Hi Meyer, you've captured the scenario in question. The parameters are sent via HTTP-Post. The format of the params hash is {"to"=>"1234565", "from"=>"543216", "text"=>"test a ", "keyword"=>"mo", "status"=>"0", "call-id"=>"45", "call-price"=>"0.0.067"} and I will have to convert 'call-id' and 'call-price' keys into 'call_id' and 'call_price' respectively.

Comment: As I also was sure that this was a design pattern, but I still haven't found a widely recommended way to achieve this. In light of your comment a better question is how to modify the params hash keys elegantly

Comment: In order to modify the keys in the params hash something along those lines could be used perhaps?                                                                                                                                                                            p
=> {"to"=>"1234565", "from"=>"543216", "text"=>"test a ", "keyword"=>"mo", "status"=>"0", "call-id"=>"45", "call-price"=>"0.0.067"} 

 > p.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.tr('-', '_') }
 
=> {"to"=>"1234565", "from"=>"543216", "text"=>"test a ", "keyword"=>"mo", "status"=>"0", "call_id"=>"45", "call_price"=>"0.0.067"}

Comment: @Meyer the issue is resolved with a method and filter as so:                                                                          `before_action :transform`

  `def transform
      #convert parameters with hyphen to parameters with underscore.
      params.deep_transform_keys! { |key| key.tr('-', '_') }
  end`

Answer (score 1):

You can customize field name in ActiveRecord. If you want to ignore default convention of rails and want to apply your own convention, here is how you can configure it :
Example :

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'sysid'
end
```

Now here primary key for `projects` table would be `sysid` and not `id` .

Here is good documentation of `ActiveRecord` class method `primary_key`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for your answer, I think @Meier's was closer to the scenario mentioned, the question was not specifically about primary key(s).

Comment: I agree with you :-)